# Record tuples in the vector result recorder

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am running a simulation in OMNeT++ 4.4 in which my nodes emit a result that is essentially a tuple. The values of the tuple are interdependent, and all nodes emit them; i.e., there are several such tuples emitted at a single simtime. The tuples cannot be "compressed" down into a single double value.

I would like to record these tuples in a vector. Is there a way to emit a data structure for statistics collection and have it recorded in the *.vec file created by OMNeT++? I do not care about the statistic functions that are available in the NED file for this particular signal.

For a simple example, suppose I have

```
typedef boost::tuple<boost::DateTime, bool, Unit::Watt, Unit::VAr> MyTuple;
```

somewhere as the data type of the signal I'd like to emit. Is there a way to have

```
MyTuple myTuple( /* ... data ... */ );
emit(mySignal, myTuple);
```

in my source code and record it in the recular `.vec` result file, e.g., like:

```
vector 1 MyNodeName MyResultVectorName TV
1  14.126 2013-01-22T23:22:19+10:00 true 125300 12000
```

If not possible, what would be the best way to still use OMNeT's signal mechanism but create the output file myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default OMNeT++ cannot save tuples (as the built-in tools would not be able to process it anyway), but a signal can carry a `cObject` similarly how scalar values are transmitted. Derive you tuple from `cObject` and you will be able to emit it with a signal. Obviously you have to also write and register a ResultRecorder (derived from `cResultRecorder`) that could handle the given datatype and write out to a file.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me alot! Where do I get the path of the result directory from, i.e., what is configured in omnetpp.ini for scalar and vector result files? I'd like to use the schema for vector files to place my custom result file in the same dir and name it the same way, just with another extension.

Comment: getEnvir()->getConfig()->getAsFilename(CFGID_OUTPUT_VECTOR_FILE).c_str() what is used by OMNeT's FileOutputVectorManager.